# Python: Text file into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, file-handling

I want to covert text file into key value pair line wise.
My text file

```
21:54:26     From Rohan luthra : yes
21:54:36     From Ankit : yup
21:54:36     From Ankit : yup
21:55:04     From Rajesh : shubh shubh bolo sir
```

What I want to do is to convert into key value pair like

```
{'Rohan luthra' : 'yes',
'Ankit' : 'yup,}
```

like this ^
I couldn't find any fitting solution.
What I did

```
with open(x) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    with open(x, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            splitLine = line.split()
            temp_dict[(splitLine[0])] = " ".join(splitLine[2:])
            # Dirty hack to remove timestamp
            temp_array = temp_dict.values()
            chat_dict = dict(s.split(':') for s in temp_array)
            pp.pprint(temp_dict)
```

But this method fails when it encounters two ":" in a line.
It returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filereader.py", line 37, in <module>
    most_talkative()
  File "filereader.py", line 32, in most_talkative
    chat_dict = dict(s.split(':') for s in temp_array)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #35 has length 3; 2 is required
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: If there is no fitting solution, please make one, show your efforts, and then ask a question if you get stuck.

Comment: What does "fails" mean?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filereader.py", line 37, in <module>
    most_talkative()
  File "filereader.py", line 32, in most_talkative
    chat_dict = dict(s.split(':') for s in temp_array)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #35 has length 3; 2 is required

Comment: Don't use a comprehension.  Break that up into a true loop, split before the call to dict() and only use the first 2 values of each split in the dict() call.  Or use other logic if you need the information after the second ':'  I guess you could send s.split(':')[:2] to the dict() call in the comprehension as well.

Comment: Well it does work :) thanks ! 
But loop works for 20 lines only, while file has 100+ lines

Comment: Are you sure it only works for a limited number of lines, or do you have repeating keys?  If you have repeating keys, you may need to create an array in each key to save multiple values to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following creates a dictionary from an arbitrary length version of the file format provided.  Keep in mind that there can only be 1 value for each key, so repeated keys will be overwritten by later values.

```
x = 'path\\to\\file'
temp_dict = dict()
chat_dict = dict()
with open(x, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split()
        temp_dict[(splitLine[0])] = " ".join(splitLine[2:])
        # Dirty hack to remove timestamp
        temp_array = temp_dict.values()
        chat_dict.update(dict(s.split(':')[:2] for s in temp_array))
print(chat_dict)
```

Comment: I have repeating keys !

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(x) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    with open(x, 'r') as y:
        for line in y:
            splitLine = line.split()
            temp_dict[(splitLine[0])] = " ".join(splitLine[2:])
            # Dirty hack to remove timestamp
            temp_array = temp_dict.values()
            chat_dict = dict(s.split(':')[:2] for s in temp_array)
```

This seems to work !
Solution given by @Alan Leuthard

Loops works for 20 lines only while actual file is of 100+ lines+

returning len(lines) gives actual no. of lines in the file i.e. 119.